# Why are my plots being displayed separately, rather than on the same graph?

Tags: python, data-visualization

I have created two line plots with this [dataset](https://www.kaggle.com/saurograndi/airplane-crashes-since-1908). The first lineplot shows the number of flight accidents in a given year. The second lineplot shows the number of fatalities in a given year. I want to put both line plots on the same graph. This is the code I have used:

```
fatalities=df[['Fatalities','Date']]
fatalities['Year of Fatality']=fatalities['Date'].dt.year
fatalities.drop('Date',inplace=True)
fatalities.set_index('Year of Fatality',inplace=True)
fatalities.sort_index(inplace=True)


plt.figure(figsize=(12,9))
plt.title("Number of Flight Accidents Since 1908",fontsize=20)
plt.ylabel("Number of Flight Accidents")
plt.xlabel("Year")
plt.xticks(year.index,rotation=90)
year.plot()
fatalities.plot()
plt.show()
```

What I get are two plots, with on above the other: the plot which shows the number of fatalities and the plot which shows the number of flight accidents.

[image]

What I want is one graph that shows the two line plots. Any help would be much appreciated. (Side note: how can I rotate the xticks 90 degrees? I used the rotation argument in the plt.xticks() but this had zero affect).

Comment: try replacing `year.plot()` with `plt.plot(year)`, and likewise for `fatalities`. Does that fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the use of `.plot()` and variables called `df`, I assume you're using pandas dataframes (if that's not the case, the answer still probably applies, look up the docs for your `plot` function).

Pandas' `plot` by default puts the plots in their own axis, unless you pass one to draw on via the `ax` attribute:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
year.plot(ax=ax)
fatalities.plot(ax=ax)
```